# populate uipicker with contentsOfDirectory Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview, nsfilemanager

I am new to swift and am trying to populate a uipicker with the file names from a folder I have created within my documents directory called "Dates".

I can list the files using this code:

```
func listFilesFromDatesFolder() {

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String

        let path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Dates")

        let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if let allItems = manager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil) {
            println(allItems)
        }
}
```

**I am just unsure how to get the list into an array that I can load the picker with in swift.**

I have done this before in a previous app using objective c:

```
NSFileManager *directoryContent;

NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *contractorDir= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:contractorTwo.text];

NSError *err;directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:contractorDir error: err];


NSArray *sorted = [directoryContent sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

I'm hoping someone can help with this and thanking you in advance if you can!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let (filenamesOpt, errorOpt) = contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Users")
        if let filenames = filenamesOpt {
            println(filenames)                // [".localized", "kris", ...]
        }

        let (filenamesOpt2, errorOpt2) = contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/NoSuchDirectory")
        if let err = errorOpt2 {
            err.description         // "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. ... "
        }

        getContentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Users") { (result, error) in
            if let e = error {
                e.description
            }
            else if let filenames = result {
                filenames                     // [".localized", "kdj", ... ]
            }
        }

        getContentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/NoSuchDirectory") { (result, error) in
            if let e = error {
                e.description                // "Error Domain=NSCocoaError..."
            }
            else if let filenames = result {
                filenames
            }
        }

        // Do something with the files in my home directory
        let listMyFiles = { block in self.getContentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Users/kdj", block: block) }

        listMyFiles { (result, error) in
            if let e = error {
                e.description
            }
            else if let filenames = result {
                filenames                     // [".bashrc", ... ]
            }
        }
    }

    // Tuple result

    // Get contents of directory at specified path, returning (filenames, nil) or (nil, error)
    func contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path: String) -> (filenames: [String]?, error: NSError?) {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let contents = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: &error)
        if contents == nil {
            return (nil, error)
        }
        else {
            let filenames = contents as! [String]
            return (filenames, nil)
        }
    }

    // Continuation Passing Style (CPS) interface

    // Get contents of directory at specified path, invoking block with (filenames, nil) or (nil, error)
    func getContentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path: String, block: (filenames: [String]?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let contents = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: &error)
        if contents == nil {
            block(filenames: nil, error: error)
        }
        else {
            let filenames = contents as! [String]
            block(filenames: filenames, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Reference from [HERE](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/dc733dfa3d55df6cc612).

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I have actually looked at the sample code provided before and it doesn't really help me get the filenames into an array that I can load the picker with. This is how I load the picker at the moment to test it: let pickerData = ["One","two","three","four"]

Comment: func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        standingCharge.text = pickerData[row]

Comment: I just need to know how to create an array from the file list and then load it into the picker, similar to the pre populated array called 'pickerData' in the above code.

Comment: Check out this sample project : https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Show-Document-Directory

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!

This code example worked a treat!

https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Show-Document-Directory

The only major change for me to show the file list in the picker, was that I had to connect my picker delegate to the view controller:

class ViewTwo: UIViewController,  **UIPickerViewDelegate** {

.......and then declare it after 'ViewDidLoad'like this:

filePicker.delegate = self

UiPickerDataSource was not required, and threw up an exception when I did try and connect it to the viewController.

Thanks Again!